# Birefringence in uniaxial materials

Tags: optics, waves, optical-materials, birefringence

In linear optics, when treating anisotropic uniaxial materials we get the frensel equation [image]

this equation gives us two solution for n. My problem is that according to Snell's law, if I have two different n, I suppose to get to different transimission angles (with two different k). In addition, each k have two eigen polarizations (with two different poynting vectors S). So I expect to get four differents beams when pointing a laser into anisotropic uniaxial material.

I know that in reality I will only get 2 different beams and I am not sure why.

I think that the problem may lay in Snell's law understaing (maybe this law relates to the angles of poynting vector S and not of the wave vector k?)

I will be happy if somone can clarify what happans here.

Comment: The two different k **are** those of the two different polarizations. So you are wrongly counting the effect twice.

Comment: But in fresnel equation I have two solution for the same k....

Answer (score 1):

The Fresnel equation you provide gives the solution of 2 refractive indices for each direction of propagation *inside* the anisotropic medium while Snell's law describes what happens on the *interface* between two mediums. In an anisotropic medium, there are 2 allowed eigenpolarizations, orthogonal to each other, for each propagation direction (wavevector). Therefore, when an incident wave arrives at the interface, according to the Fresnel equation, there are 2 refracted waves, having orthogonal polarization. Since they both experience different refractive indices at the interface, each of them refracts according to Snell's law, hence different refraction angles.

Snell's law relates the angle of wavevector from the normal to the interface, not the Poynting vector. All the wavevectors would stay in a single plane, called the incidence plane while the Poynting vector could even stay out of the incidence plane and there is no general law relating it.